# Where is the appropriate place to solicit framework-selection advice?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I've seen many questions, of varying quality and specificity, soliciting advice on selecting PHP frameworks closed.* And I've see [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580157/best-framework-for-making-webbased-games-in-java) that [remain open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575200/which-is-the-best-php-framework-to-use-for-php-5) (and have even enjoyed a handful of upvotes).

I'd like to get advice on choosing a PHP framework that will facilitate migrating a legacy P/L SQL system built almost entirely within Oracle, by developers who pretty much only know P/L SQL. I don't know enough PHP to know what I don't know (ya know?), but [I understand the framework will need to work well with OCI8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf) (see chapter 3).

**What is the appropriate way to go about soliciting the community's wisdom for this selection?** Is there a way to phrase the question so it's not "what's the best", but rather "which have you had success with"? Or is there some Stack Overflow discussion forum outside the norms of the Q&A area? Or is any question that doesn't have a demonstrable "one true answer" just...*ineligible* for this site?

*-examples of closed questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186800/what-is-the-best-php-framework
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637135/the-best-php-basic-framework
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081178/best-php-framework-with-oracle
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573057/best-php-framework-for-jquery
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227679/best-php-framework-that-supports-responsive-design

Comment: Evil, nasty shopping questions...

Comment: If you find any other similar questions that are still open please continue posting them. I'd love to use all my close votes.

Comment: You could use chat.stackoverflow.com, there is a [php room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php). You could ask there, but getting advise isn't really suited on the main stackoverflow site (or any StackExchange site).

Comment: Check out job posts and try work out what's not on the decline

Comment: @random might have the right of it. </ martin>

Comment: hm... the 'where to post' tag is replaced by scope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there isn't a 'recommended' place for this. Your best bet would be the Stack Overflow [PHP chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), but I cannot guarantee that you will find an answer there.

Stack Exchange sites rarely look kindly on shopping/list questions, so if you post this as a question, it will likely get down-voted, closed, and possibly deleted.

As I cannot really stop you, if you MUST ask this question outside of chat, you should ask on Stack Overflow, as it deals with coding and related tools.

I response to your question

> is any question that doesn't have a demonstrable "one true answer"
> just...*ineligible* for this site?,

Although they are eligible, as deemed by the FAQ:

> but if your question generally covers …
>
> ```
> a specific programming problem
> a software algorithm
> software tools commonly used by programmers
> practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
> ```
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

the community generally frowns upon these questions, as the answers are often loose, and cannot be easily proven. Ultimately, the community gets to choose what questions stay and which ones are removed.

Source of requirements quote: [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: This answer was partly based off of George Duckett's comment on the above question

Comment: Even *asking* where to post got a down-vote (counter-balanced by an upvote). Sigh.

Comment: @JeromyFrench, that is not the first time, and won't be the last. It happened to me too, but I think that I netted a positive vote total for the question

Comment: So I visited the PHP chat room and was told not to bother with a Framework, and that Oracle connectivity is baked into PHP and doesn't have to be implemented by a framework. So...there's that.

Comment: That's more than you would have gotten by asking a question, and it's a start.